# Sequelize Joining tables not created when trying to use single create call with embedded object

Tags: sequelize.js

I am new to Sequelize and trying to follow [their example](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html) for creating, in my case a User that has many Roles.

The following code snippet works as expected with my configuration. This creates the user and creates the UserRole table.

```js
    const adminRole = await Role.create( {role: 'admin'} );
    const basicRole = await Role.create( {role: 'basic'} );
    const user = await User.create( userData, options );
    user.addRoles([adminRole, basicRole])
```

However, I can't seem to get the single create a call to work. I would like to do this so I don't have to query the database to get the role objects when I will know the FK ahead of time. Forgive the code formatting, it is to conserve space in the question.

```js
    // define the role table
    class Role extends Model{}
    Role.init( { role: { primaryKey: true, type: Sequelize.DataTypes.TEXT() } },
               { sequelize, modelName: 'Role' }
             );

    // define the user table
    class User extends Model{}
    User.init({ 
        id: { type: Sequelize.DataTypes.UUID, defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
            allowNull:false, primaryKey: true, },
        nameUser: { type: Sequelize.DataTypes.TEXT(),  allowNull:false }},
        { sequelize, modelName: 'User' });


    // define the joining table
    class UserRole extends Model {}
    UserRole.init({}, { sequelize: db.db,  modelName: 'UserRole' }

    // Link the table via the UserRole table
    Role.belongsToMany( User, {through: UserRole} );
    User.belongsToMany( Role, {through: UserRole} );


    // At some stage in the lifecycle of the app this guy is added to the database
    const admin = await Role.create({role: 'admin'});


    // later on in my route handler....
    const userData =  { nameUser: 'test-name-2', roles:[{role:'admin'}] };
    const options = { include: Role };

    // No join table is created. 
    const user = await User.create( userData, options );
```

I have tried so many variations of objects and key names. But I can't seem to recreate the behaviour that is achieved through the

```js
    user.addRoles([])
```

What am I doing wrong, or what do I not understand. I appreciate any guidance and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I got the correct combination working and added some better error logging.

```js
    const userData =  { nameUser: 'test-name-2', Roles:[ {role:'admin'} ] };
    const options = { include: Role };

    // No join table is created, yet a new Role is. 
    const user = await User.create( userData, options );
```

So it looks like the part I didn't understand was that the create call wasn't going to create my UserRole table but instead create another Role entry. As the Role already existed, I was getting an error on must be unique. I am not sure if it is even possible to create the user table automatically when creating the user entry.